# debugging in android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am using eclipse as the IDE and I have written small programs but now I want to debug them so that i could check the flow of control

Comment: What is the question? How to debug?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse you can just set a breakpoint as in any usual Java Application and then do a right click on your project and select Debug as -> Android Application instead of Run as -> Android Application. Now Eclipse will connect the debugger to your emulator or phone and open the debugger once you are reaching the breakpoint.

If the breakpoint is not reached have a look at your manifest.xml file and be sure to mark your application as debuggable.

For that you have to add the attribute debuggable to your application tag.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:name="Name"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
```

Comment: New SDK/AVD will add this debuggable attribute automatically. However, you have to remove it manually. It's in the manifest file.